# Matlab - Shape from focus

Tags: matlab, image-processing, focus, shapes, depth

Given an image I have calculated the depth of every point in the image and I need to plot a map like this in MATLAB. Can someone suggest how I would go about this.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have your depth data stored in a 2D array called `D`, then you need to decide upon the gridded domain above which to plot `D`. I will assume that you care about the x-axis range `[x_min, x_max]` and the y-axis range `[y_min, y_max]`, where these are each scalars that represent the minimum and maximum for each coordinate direction.

```
y_num = size(D,1); % <-- Number of points to use in y-axis grid.
x_num = size(D,2); % <-- Number of points to use in x-axis grid.

x_grid_vals = linspace(x_min,x_max,x_num);
y_grid_vals = linspace(y_min,y_max,y_num);

% Get full coordinate grid for the 3D plot.
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x_grid_vals,y_grid_vals);

% Plot the data.
% The surf() function plots the depth as 3D above the created grid.
surf(X,Y,D);
```

[Here is the `surf()` documentation.](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/surf.html)